# Нужно сделать так, чтобы функция выполнялась только один раз при первом запуске

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю скрипт, в котором одна из функций создает папки на компьютере.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы это функция выполнялась только один раз при первом запуске программы, а при дальнейших запусках нет. Каким образом это можно сделать?
Функция

```
def create_dirs(folder_sort):
    for i in dirs:
        try:
            os.mkdir(folder_sort + i)
        except OSError:
            k = input(f'Directory {i} already exists, do you want to recreate it?\nAnswer y/n: ')
            if k == 'y':
                shutil.rmtree(folder_sort + i)
                os.mkdir(folder_sort + i)
            elif k == 'n':
                pass
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять пустой файл и при каждом запуске программы записывать (или перезаписывать) в файл какое - либо значение, и также проверять на то, является ли файл пустым.

```
def func():
    f = open('result.ini', 'w') # и в функции записывать в файл значение
    b = f.write("The function was completed")
    f.close()
    print("123")

f = open('result.ini', 'r') #при каждом запуске читаются данные
a = f.read()
f.close()

if a == "": #если файл пустой - выполнить функцию
    func()
```

И при следующем запуске файл не будет пустым и функция не вызовется.

Или как сказал Alexandr Kiselev ловить FileExistsError:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(folder_sort + i)
except FileExistsError:
    break
```

Comment: Я рассматривал такой вариант.
А нет какого-нибудь декоратора, который выполняет такую же функцию, которую вы описали?

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev тогда нужно не закрывать процесс или оставлять его в фоне, чтобы сохранить данные от том, сколько раз выполнилась функция. Если вы его закроете или перезагрузите пк, оперативная память, в которой хранятся данные о том, сколько раз выполнилась функция - очистится. И при след запуске папки будут созданы снова

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `shelve`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: import os

In [6]: def to_create(prefix, dirs):
   ...:     new_dirs = []
   ...:     for dir_ in dirs:
   ...:         if not os.isdir(prefix + dir_):
   ...:             new_dirs.append(dir_)
   ...:     return new_dirs
   ...:

In [7]: def create_dirs(folder_sort):
   ...:     for i in to_create(folder_sort, dirs):
   ...:         os.mkdir(folder_sort + i)
```

Находим все директории которые еще не существуют и создаем их. Если все директории уже существуют - ничего не делаем.